# Turn off Ckfiner access to public

Tags: javascript, asp.net

On asp platform using CkFinder, How do I turn off public access to /ckfinder/ckfinder.html

I have an area that requires login to access, yet when not logged in we can access this page

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the CkFinder configuration file, you can have it hide files, or folders, or files and folders, as explained here:

http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/Java/Configuration/Hiding_Folders_and_Files

So, essentially you want to do:

```
<hideFiles>
  <file>ckfinder.html</file>
</hideFiles>
```

**EDIT**

You can also use the ACL to limit what roles can view what folders, as explained here:

http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/PHP/Configuration/Access_Control

without testing it myself, restricting anonymous users from the folder will:

```
$config['AccessControl'][] = Array(
'role' => '*',
'resourceType' => '*',
'folder' => '/CkFinder', 

'folderView' => false,
'folderCreate' => false,
'folderRename' => false,
'folderDelete' => false,

'fileView' => false,
'fileUpload' => false,
'fileRename' => false,
'fileDelete' => false);
```

Comment: I am in asp.net not php